# The as.Date() Function does not work, my characters remain characters

Tags: readxl

I have an Excel File in which there is a column containing the date and hour of a regarding measurment in the format `01.01.2018 01:00`.

The first 3 rows contain characters, the whole column is formatted as "Number" (in Excel/libre)

If I try to read the xlxs file with readxl:

```
NO2_2018 <- read_excel("NO2_2018.xlsx", sheet = "Seite 1", 
                       range = "A2:AU8762", col_types = c("date", 
                                                          "numeric", ....)
```

I get NA Values (format is `POSIXct`) and the warning

```
Expecting date in .... / .....: got '03.01.2018 02:00'
```

Then I thought I read it as "txt" and then convert it with `as.Date()` function:

```
as.Date(NO2_2018$Zeitpunkt,format = "%d.%m.%Y% H:%M", tz="CEST")
```

However, it does not change the class

```
class(NO2_2018$Zeitpunkt)
[1] "character"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the dot in the date and then use the as.date in your transformed variable?

```
(gsub(".", "/", date)
```

Comment: NO2_2018_2 <- gsub(".","/",NO2_2018$Zeitpunkt)


view(NO2_2018_2)
That change the entire entries to "/////////"  not just the points

Comment: NO2_2018_2 <- gsub("\\D","/",NO2_2018$Zeitpunkt,ignore.case=T) worked to transform